# Opening a photo with tempfile in Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to process a photo sent by client to my Telegram bot. To do this I'm willing to use tempfile to ease the process and not filling the disk. I'm using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot)

The code looks like this:

```py
def get_exif(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
        update.message.photo[-1].get_file().download(out=f)
        f.seek(0)

        print(exifread.process_file(f))
```

This prints an empty dictionary, although I'm pretty sure the file has exif info. I tried it with the following codes to debug if something is wrong with anything else that I can not see. The followings are working well:

```py
# the same file with the telegram code
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    exifread.process_file(f)
```

Or:

```py
# I tried this to see if something wrong with my
# usage of tempfile. may look stupid
with open(p, 'rb') as f:
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tf:
        tf.write(f.read())
        tf.seek(0)
        exifread.process_file(tf)
```

What am I missing here?

**Edit 1:**
I'm sharing the complete code, all you need to do is paste your bot's token to `TOKEN` and is should be working.

```py
"""
Module for keep telegram bot and related functions.

This is the main script to run telegram bot.
"""
import tempfile
from os import getenv
from pprint import pformat
from typing import Tuple

import dotenv
from PIL import Image
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import (CallbackContext, Dispatcher, Filters, MessageHandler,
                          Updater)
import exifread


TOKEN = ""


def get_exif(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    """Get the photo with largest size from message and send exif info."""
    # with tempfile.TemporaryFile('wb+') as f:
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
        update.message.photo[-1].get_file().download()

        print(exifread.process_file(
            f, stop_tag='EXIF', details=False, auto_seek=True))


def set_updater() -> Tuple[Updater, Dispatcher]:
    """Set updaters."""
    updater = Updater(token=TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    image_handler = MessageHandler(
        Filters.photo & (~Filters.command), get_exif)
    dispatcher.add_handler(image_handler)

    return updater, dispatcher


if __name__ == '__main__':
    updater, _ = set_updater()

    updater.start_polling()
```

**Edit 2:**
I'm using Ubuntu. When I right click to image to see its properties, I can see details in it. But I can't see them neither in the downloaded temporary file (in `/tmp`) or when I "save image as" in Telegram's interface.

So can we say that the details are lost when you send a photo in telegram? Is it possible?

Comment: So in the second example you are saving to `filename` the photo you obtain from `update.message.photo[-1].get_file().download(...)`? What library are you using for Telegram? Adding a complete [mre] of a very simple bot that reproduces the problem would help.

Comment: Hello, I have edited the question to add the code. I'm using https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot

Answer (score 1):

This maybe doesn't answer your actual question, but to download a `telegram.File` without writing to disk you can

- use [`File.download_as_bytearray`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.file.html#telegram.File.download_as_bytearray)
- instead of writing to a tempfile, write to a bytestring, as done e.g. [here](https://gitlab.com/HirschHeissIch/twitter-status-bot/-/blob/master/bot/twitter.py#L229-233)